# Which date time format are the following dates?

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-formatting

Which date format is this 
 `Fri, 30 Oct 2015 16:49:37 +0800` ?

I found it when i was parsing a page today . Is the last part about time zone ?

---

**an Extension to the above question**

Which date format is this `Sun, 01 Nov 2015 09:00:00 Z` ?

I tried with `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z` and it didnot work.

Comment: yes, that is a timezone offset.

Comment: how do i handle it ?

Comment: what did you try out?

Comment: EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz

Comment: @sidgate  `Fri, 30 Oct 2015 09:30:00 Z` this one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part `+800` is an alternative for providing timezone. A `SimpleDateFormat` that matches your example would be :

```
"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
```

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: `Fri, 30 Oct 2015 09:30:00 Z`  what about this ?

Comment: If you have an actual timezone at the end it will parse correctly assuming 9:00AM